# I'm looking for query parameter that should be set to get year based public holidays

Tags: c#, google-api, google-calendar-api

```
public Events GetCalendar(string calendarID, int year)
{
    EventsResource.ListRequest request = service.Events.List(calendarID);
    request.TimeMin = new DateTime(year, 1, 1);
    request.TimeMax = new DateTime(year, 12, 31);
    request.ShowDeleted = false;
    request.SingleEvents = true;
    request.OrderBy = EventsResource.ListRequest.OrderByEnum.StartTime;
    // List events.
    Events events = request.Execute();
    if (events.Items.Count > 0)
        return events;
    else
        return null;
}
```

Input (primary,2015) ==> Output: null
What parameter should be used to get calendar event for previous year?

Comment: try to pass time while creating `DateTime` object.
`request.TimeMin = new DateTime(2015, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);
    request.TimeMax = new DateTime(2015, 12, 31, 23, 59, 59);`

Comment: For getting public holidays, I think, you need to access google public calendars.

Comment: Calendar Ids for public calendars are like en.usa#holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com   for USA and en.india#holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com for INDIA.

Comment: I recommend testing it here.   Public holiday calendars arnt prefect especially when trying to go back a few years https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/calendar/v3/calendar.events.list?calendarId=en.danish%2523holiday%2540group.v.calendar.google.com&_h=24&